Investigating "Access violation in unknown section at address 0xffffffffffffffff of size 32"
After reading: How to investigate access violation errors, I feel like this error is different from a variety of reasons:

I'm modifying an existing (working) Anchor project, and strictly using less memory, therefore I find it unlikely that it is a stack overflow issue.

How might I debug this issue?
Is there anyway to get a line number when Solana is throwing this error?
The code for my program:
pub fn taker<'info>(
    ctx: Context<'_, '_, '_, 'info, Taker<'info>>,
    price: u64,
    amount: u64,
    is_bid: bool,
    market_index: u16,
    pos_limit: i64
) -> Result<()> {
    let taker = ctx.accounts.user.load()?;

    let (base_init, _) = taker
        .get_perp_position(market_index)
        .map_or((0, 0), |p| (p.base_asset_amount, p.quote_asset_amount));
    
    drop(taker);

    if is_bid &&  base_init + amount as i64 > pos_limit {
        return Err(ErrorCode::PosLimitBreached.into())
    } 

    if !is_bid &&  -base_init + amount as i64 > pos_limit {
        return Err(ErrorCode::PosLimitBreached.into())
    }

    let order_params = OrderParams {
        order_type: OrderType::Limit,
        market_type: MarketType::Perp,
        direction: if is_bid { PositionDirection::Long } else { PositionDirection::Short },
        user_order_id: 0,
        base_asset_amount: amount,
        price: price,
        market_index,
        reduce_only: false,
        post_only: PostOnlyParam::None,
        immediate_or_cancel: true,
        max_ts: None,
        trigger_price: None,
        trigger_condition: OrderTriggerCondition::Above,
        oracle_price_offset: None,
        auction_duration: None,
        auction_start_price: None,
        auction_end_price: None,
    };

    place_and_take(&ctx, order_params)?;

    let taker = ctx.accounts.user.load()?;
    let (base_end, _) = taker
        .get_perp_position(order_params.market_index)
        .map_or((0, 0), |p| (p.base_asset_amount, p.quote_asset_amount));

    if base_end == base_init {
        return Err(ErrorCode::NoFill.into());
    }

    Ok(())
}

This is a modified version of the original contract here:
https://github.com/drift-labs/jit-proxy/blob/master/programs/jit-proxy/src/instructions/arb_perp.rs
I've modified this existing (deployed) contract that seems to work, so I assume I must've messed up somewhere. I'm still learning Rust, so would like to learn how to I can debug these issues in the future.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The answer here was my program was compiled with an incompatible version of Solana on my system. Looking at the cargo lock file showed 1.14 as a dep, but I had 1.18 installed.
